# Is Nelson's stochastic mechanics wrong, and if so, why?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Is it [Nelson's stochastic interpretation of QM, and other similar theories] wrong?

I honestly do not know but would be very happy to be educated and/or referred to a paper describing an experimental result that unambigiuosly favors QM over stochastic interpretations of particle motion.

Comment: I assume you mean Nelson's book *Quantum Fluctuations*. The book R.F. Streater, *Lost Causes* which used to exist as a web page at Kings College London and later appeared in print should help you further. Streater writes that Nelson "abandoned it as not correct physics. See Nelson's contribution to 'Field Theory and the Future of Stochastic Mechanics', in *Stochastic Processes in Classical and Quantum Systems*, Lect. Notes in Phys 262, p 438, 1986. Springer-Verlag."

Comment: @Kurt G. Thanks for the Streater reference. The issue I run into that there are clearly two camps. The larger camp based in Copenhagen (includes Streater) and the other smaller camp is more dispersed. Hence wondering if there is any empirical (and thus as objective as possible) refutation of Nelson's mechanics. But perhaps this empirical evidence is part of Streater's book.

Comment: Streater's book seems more of a compilation (I read only a pdf file I found in the internet but ordered the printed version from amazon). Probably best if you try to dig out the reference *Stochastic Processes in Classical and Quantum Systems* that Streater refers to. BTW if you have stuff to read from the two camps pls post where to find it. Further please see [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7220/web-references-for-nelsons-quantum-fluctuations?rq=1).